# How to make child node of a treeview control to make panel control visible

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

how to write a click event for a child node of a tree view control...
if i click the child node a static panel should be visible.

Comment: 1. Please don't just add "(c# ASP.net)" and such to your titles. That's what the tags are for. 2. Please use real English words, not "pls" and "ur". 3. Please omit "thanks in advance", signatures, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know , the only way is to programatically tell which node is selected (retrieve the appropriate node via the e.Node parameter), then fire the corresponding functionality.
This code can be placed within TreeView.AfterSelect event.

Comment: protected void NavigationMenu_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeView1.Nodes.Clear();
        DataSet ds = obj.populate_tree_types(Convert.ToInt32(NavigationMenu.SelectedValue));
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            TreeNode root = new TreeNode(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());
            root.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Expand;
            CreateNode(root);
            TreeView1.Nodes.Add(root);
        }    

    }

Comment: void CreateNode(TreeNode node)
    {
        
        DataSet ds = obj.populate_tree_Categories(Convert.ToString(node.Text), Convert.ToInt32(NavigationMenu.SelectedValue));
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
               TreeNode tnode = new TreeNode(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());
                tnode.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Expand;
                node.ChildNodes.Add(tnode);
                CreateNode(tnode);

Comment: @VinothEzhilanM: Please edit your question to include that code. It's not readable in a comment.

Comment: childNode =  TreeNodeSelectAction.Select; this helpes me to do so.... string selectedNode = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text.ToString().Trim(); by this i can access child node...